# Facebook Friend's information is not properly fetched

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am facing some difficulty in getting the facebook friend's information of logged in user.

I am creating Facebook integrated asp.net application. I am not able to fetch facebook

friend's birthday and relationship status though they are public.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Birth Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("birthday") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Please help,

Thanks,

Isha.

Answer (score 0):

You need `user_birthday` and `user_relationships` permissions to display this information.

For more details see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/